# How to solve this system of logarithm equations?

Tags: logarithms, systems-of-equations

$x^{log_8(y)}+y^{log_8(x)}=4\\log_4(x)-log_4(y)=1$

I have no idea how to start this.

Comment: The second relation clearly implies $x = 4y$. Use this further in the first expression.

Comment: I tried it. I got $y^{\frac{2}{3}+log_8(y)}+y^{log_8(4y))}=4$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^{log_8(y)}+y^{log_8(x)}=4$$
$$y^{log_8(x)}+y^{log_8(x)}=4$$
$$2y^{log_8(x)}=4$$
$$y^{log_8(x)}=2$$
$$log_8(x)=log_y (2)$$
Again, we have $$log_4(x)-log_4(y)=1$$
$$log_4(\frac{x}{y})=1$$
$$(\frac{x}{y})=4^1$$
$$x=4y$$
Hence from first relation we have,
$$log_{2^3}(4y)=log_y (2)$$
$$\frac{1}{3}(2+log_2 (y))=log_y (2)$$
Say $log_y (2)=a$ 
Above equation becomes
$$\frac{1}{3}(2+\frac{1}{a})=a$$
$$3a^2-2a-1=o$$
$$3a^2-3a+a-1=o$$
$$(3a+1)(a-1)=0$$
Hence $a=1$ or $-\frac{1}{3}$ 
For $a=1$ 
So, $y=2$ and $x=8$ 
And for $a=-\frac{1}{3}$ 
$y=\frac{1}{8}$ and $x=\frac{1}{2}$

FORMULAE USED:

1. $a^{log_b(c)}=c^{log_b(a)}$
2. $log_a b=\frac{1}{log_b a}$

**EDIT:** 
1. Proof:  Say $a^{log_b(c)}= p$ 
$$log_b (a^{log_b(c)})= log_b p$$
$$log_b c \cdot log_b a = log_b p$$
$$log_b a \cdot log_b c = log_b p$$
$$log_b (c^{log_b(a)}) = log_b p$$
$$c^{log_b(a)}=p$$
Hence proved.

Comment: I don't understand your first step.  How did you conclude that $x^{\log_8 y} = y^{\log_8 x}$?

Comment: Its a formula. You want me to prove it?

Comment: I'll try proving it myself first, I just haven't seen it before.

Comment: OK. I'll give a hint. Take the LHS as "p" and take log on both sides. Then try to orient it to get RHS ="p".

Comment: I haven't seen the $a^log_b(c)=c^log_b(a)$ formula before.

Comment: I am updating my answer with proof of the above formula.

Comment: @O.Botond, use `{ }`'s to keep it all in the exponent.  `a^{\log_b(c)}` to typeset $a^{\log_b(c)}$, and @ aniket, that is a useful formula, I got it as well.  Putting that into my bag of tricks for later.

Comment: @JMoravitz Is it clear now? I have given a proof.

Comment: @O.Botond Are you comfortable with it?

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks, i will remember for this :)

Comment: @Aniket yes, now i understand :) Thanks for the formula, and the solution :)

Comment: @Aniket the $a=\frac{-1}{3}$ is a solution too, becouse the range of logarithm function is R.

Comment: @O.Botond Yes you were right. Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

$$\begin{cases}
x^{\log_8(y)}+y^{\log_8(x)}=4\\
\log_4(x)-\log_4(y)=1
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
x^{\log_8(y)}+y^{\log_8(x)}=4\\
\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(4)}-\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(4)}=1
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
x^{\log_8(y)}+y^{\log_8(x)}=4\\
\frac{\ln(x)-\ln(y)}{\ln(4)}=1
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
x^{\log_8(y)}+y^{\log_8(x)}=4\\
\ln(x)-\ln(y)=\ln(4)
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
x^{\log_8(y)}+y^{\log_8(x)}=4\\
\frac{x}{y}=4
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
x^{\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(8)}}+y^{\frac{\ln(x)}{\ln(8)}}=4\\
\frac{x}{y}=4
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
2x^{\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(8)}}=4\\
\frac{x}{y}=4
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
x^{\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(8)}}=2\\
\frac{x}{y}=4
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
\frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(x)}=\frac{\ln(y)}{\ln(8)}\\
\frac{x}{y}=4
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
\ln(2)\ln(8)=\ln(y)\ln(x)\\
\frac{x}{y}=4
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
\ln(2)\ln(8)=\ln(y)\ln(x)\\
x=4y
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
\ln(2)\ln(8)=\ln(y)\ln(4y)\\
x=4y
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
\ln(4)\ln(y)+\ln^2(y)=\ln(2)\ln(8)\\
x=4y
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
\ln(4)\ln(y)+\ln^2(y)+\frac{\ln^2(4)}{4}=\ln(2)\ln(8)+\frac{\ln^2(4)}{4}\\
x=4y
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
\left(\ln(y)+\frac{\ln(4)}{2}\right)^2=\ln(2)\ln(8)+\frac{\ln^2(4)}{4}\\
x=4y
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
\ln(y)+\frac{\ln(4)}{2}=\pm\sqrt{\ln(2)\ln(8)+\frac{\ln^2(4)}{4}}\\
x=4y
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
\ln(y)=\pm\sqrt{\ln(2)\ln(8)+\frac{\ln^2(4)}{4}}-\frac{\ln(4)}{2}\\
x=4y
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
y=e^{\pm\sqrt{\ln(2)\ln(8)+\frac{\ln^2(4)}{4}}-\frac{\ln(4)}{2}}\\
x=4y
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
y_1=e^{\sqrt{\ln(2)\ln(8)+\frac{\ln^2(4)}{4}}-\frac{\ln(4)}{2}} \vee y_2=e^{-\sqrt{\ln(2)\ln(8)+\frac{\ln^2(4)}{4}}-\frac{\ln(4)}{2}}\\
x=4y
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\begin{cases}
y_1=\frac{1}{8} \vee y_2=2\\
x=4y
\end{cases}\Longleftrightarrow$$

$$\begin{cases}
y_1=\frac{1}{8} \vee y_2=2\\
x_1=\frac{1}{2} \vee x_2=8
\end{cases}$$

---

We got 4 solutions:

$$x_1=\frac{1}{2},y_1=\frac{1}{8}$$
$$x_2=8,y_2=2$$

Comment: You wrote $x\cdot y=4$, but it should instead be $\frac{x}{y}=4$.  Remember that addition outside of logarithms is multiplication inside, whereas subtraction outside of logarithms is division inside.

Comment: Thanks for  your comment, you're totally right! See my edit

Comment: @JanEerland your method looks good, but how do you get the solutions for x and y?

Comment: @O.Botond Find $x=4y$ and put it in your natural logarithm formula and you get the answer for $y$ and than you fill that into your $x=4y$ and you get your $x$ solutions. I think that this is the more elegant way to find answers to a 'system of equations'

Comment: What do you mean under natural logarithm formula?

Comment: I mean $\ln(2)\ln(8)=\ln(y)\ln(4y)$

Comment: I can't understand how do you get the solutions from this formula.

Comment: How much do you know about math? (Number theory)

Comment: @O.Botond I've editted my answer and with your kowledge of math you have to understand what I'm doing there.